# Sublime Text 3 doesn't kill processes when finished

Tags: python, build, sublimetext3

Running Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu here, Version 3.2.2 build 3211.

**Problem**: When running a script with Python3 or Latex, the process stays in memory after it's finished. I have to kill them manually. I discovered this after my computer froze at least twice, and it was caused by python processes from Sublime eating up all RAM and swap. Also, I had  problems with matplotlib complaining that all available resources for new windows were taken.

**Expectation**: when a job is finished, the process should be killed, freeing up memory.

**Tests**: I didn't test with other languages besides Latex or Python. I tried in Sublime build 3210 and 3209, and it had the same behavior. I tried to look for in Sublime forums and here on Stack Overflow, and I couldn't find anything related.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Sorry, @Uni but there is no error log... the process runs correctly, but it doesn't vanishes after it ends, and it keeps using memory and allocated resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a "-i" flag in the build configuration for Python3... I copied this config somewhere and forgot to check. Now the processes are correctly closed!

About the Latex one, I will uninstall Latex packages and try to install them again.